# Issue with a js slider trying to make the current slides' div appear on top

Tags: javascript, html, css

For a js slider we're using a span "slider_link" to make the entire containing div into a clickable link. The issue is the first div seems to stay in place so the link never changes even when the slides do. We want the link for each slide to appear with that slide.

[Demo of issue](http://www.abacusnyc.com/newsite/)

HTML excerpt:

```
<div class="slider1">
<div class="slider-text slider-text1">
<a href="http://www.abacusnyc.com/about-us/overview"><span class="slider_link"></span></a>
<h1><span>Differentiate.</span> Shouldn't your recruitment firm stand out as much as you do.</h1>
<p>Human Resourcefulness is finding the right people, right now.</p>

</div>
</div>
```

CSS excerpt:

```
.slider_link { 
    float:left;
     position:absolute;
     width:100%;
     height:100%;
     top:0;
     left: 0;

  /* edit: added z-index */
      z-index:inherit;

  /* edit: fixes overlap error in IE7/8, 
     make sure you have an empty gif */
     background-image: url('../images/empty.gif');
}
```

Comment: Couple of things... your empty.gif is not found when I check out the demo.  Why do you use float:left as well as absolute positioning? And I would also suggest you put a wrapper around your sliding elements with overflow:hidden because right now, I can see the next slide before I'm supposed to: http://imgur.com/dvnLldD

Comment: In fact, without seeing the rest of your css or code, I'm going to take a stab at the fact that your absolute positioning is causing your link to stay put, especially if its parent container doesn't have position:relative set, which means that the slider link is staying absolutely positioned against the document instead of its parent.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. If it helps you can see the entire code in the demo link I included. I'm going to eliminate the float in the mean time.

Comment: Put a wrap around your slider too, set to the content width and overflow:hidden, so the rest of the slides aren't visible.  Give this wrapper relative positioning so that absolute positioning of the slider links works as expected

Comment: @HighParkCoder putting relative positioning in the wrapper that already existed solved the problem. That was basically your suggestion in the comments, don't know if you want to offer that as a formal answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put relative positioning in the wrapper div!